# fixed element with wrong position after animation CSS

Tags: css, css-position, css-transforms

Here I created [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z8fBD/6/) which kind of replicates my problem

After animation (clicking on MOVE twice), fixed column comes back with wrong position.

is it possible to animate my this without using `left` or `right` for fixed positioned element?

Comment: Works perfectly for me

Comment: strange, does not work for me in any browser (tested on windows and linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/z8fBD/7/

Trick is to add reset translate on #body

```
#body {
    position:absolute;
    left: 0;
    top:0;
    width: 200px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0%,0px);
    -moz-transform: translate(0%,0px);
    -ms-transform: translate(0%,0px);
    -o-transform: translate(0%,0px);
    transform: translate(0%,0px);
}
```

Comment: just, fixed element is not fixed anymore

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `margin:0px` and `padding:0px` to your `<body>` because position:fixed`lead element at`top` without considering padding and margin with document.

Please check here 
[`JsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/z8fBD/5/)

Comment: it should be fixed )) Even title says this)

Comment: you have an typo in css which does not apply (I guess) fixed position. as soon as I correct typo, it does not work

Comment: @Branwo Please check it now. But you have to give style to your body, because position fixed will automatically lead to top position

Comment: Okay sorry about that. Also I tried this on Safari instead of Chrome and it worked fine...

Comment: Thanks it works, but there is a problem..
Wrapper is not in body but another div, which is `margin: 0 auto`.

Can we fix that?

Answer (score -1):

Remove "position: fixed;" from the #fixed style and it works fine...

Comment: it should be fixed )) Even title says this)